# Is this property of polynomials generic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $n \geq 2$, and consider a polynomial $f$ in $n$ variables, say over a field $K$ of characteristic 0. Recall that $f$ is *geometrically irreducible* if $f$ is irreducible over the algebraic closure of $K$. We know that for $n \geq 2$, being geometrically irreducible is a generic condition, i.e., applies to a non-empty open subset (in the Zariski topology) of the space of polynomials of degree $d$, say.

It seems that some geometrically irreducible polynomials are "more" reducible than others. Here is the example I have in mind: take $f(x,y) = x^3 - y^2$, so that $f$ is geometrically irreducible. However, $f(u^2,v^3) = u^6 - v^6$ IS reducible, in fact splits completely over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Let us define two further classes of polynomials: we say that $f$ is *practically reducible* if there exist polynomials $u_1, \cdots, u_n$ such that $f(u_1, \cdots, u_n)$ is geometrically reducible, and we say that $f$ is *algebraically practically reducible* if there exist algebraic functions $u_1, \cdots, u_n$ such that $f(u_1, \cdots, u_n)$ is a polynomial which is geometrically reducible.

My questions are: is the condition of being "practically irreducible" and "algebraically practically irreducible" generic conditions? That is, do there exist non-empty Zariski-open subsets of polynomials of given degree which are not practically reducible/algebraically practically reducible?

Comment: What you call *"geometrically irreducible"* should be *"absolutely irreducible"* (while its opposite should be *"geometrically reducible"*!). Indeed usually *"geometrically P"* means "***becomes*** *P after extending scalars"* while *"absolutely P"* means "***remains*** *P" after [every] extension of scalars."*

Comment: I assume you mean that the $u_i$ should at least be algebraically independent. Even so, what if you just replace $x_1$ by $u_1:=x_1+f(x_1,...,x_n)$? Viewed as a polynomial in $x_1$ over $\mathbb{Q}(x_2,...,x_n)$, $f(u_1)$ is divisible by $f(x_1)$, and properly divisible as long as you avoid degenerate cases..

Comment: (Although maybe you mean that all the $u_i$ should be (algebraically independent) ONE-variable polynomials of the corresponding $x_i$?)

Comment: @JoachimKönig I am not sure what the most natural and reasonable condition to impose on the $x_i$'s should be, but certainly algebraic independence sounds reasonable. It would be remarkable, and perhaps even better for what I am trying to do, if in fact such a substitution always exists.